# Everythink in between / and / will printable in javascript....! why?

Tags: javascript

> Why everything  between / and / is going to print? It should give me error in console.

`console.log` normally print string enclosed within `""` or any `variable` and `object`, in below case i am not passing string or any variable and object, but still it is printable.

```js
var x = 10;
console.log(/m/);
console.log(/c/);
console.log(/&/);
console.log(/var/);
console.log(/x/);
```

Comment: Not everything. ///

Comment: We're using SQL injection here? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything between `/` and `/` is considered to be regex. So, that's why it prints them out.

---

If you do a `console.log( typeof /test/ );` it'll say `Object` which means that it **is** something.

JavaScript allows you to use the `RegExp` short hand like - `/test/` which will match the string `test` in any given sequence.

Try something like:

```
let testOne = /test/;
let testTwo = new RegExp( 'test' );

console.log( testOne.test( 'test' ) );
console.log( testTwo.test( 'test' ) );
```

the code will output:

```
true
true
```

P.S.: The function `regExp.test( String )` returns `true` if the `String` inside matches the expression defined in the `regExp` object.